# is couchDB just not the right tool for large datasets?

Tags: jquery, couchdb, couchdb-futon

I'm looking into couchDB. If i understand correctly, you can't just send a "query" to couchDB and do a partial update.

For example this document called "users" (simplified for clarity):

```
{
   allusers: [
      {"id": 1, "username":"myuser1", "pass":"secret"},
      {"id": 2, "username":"myuser2", "pass":"password"},
      {"id": 3, "username":"myuser3", "pass":"crypto"}
   ]
}
```

Is it true there isn't really a way to update user 3's password, that instead I have to load the entire document, make the update in javascript on the client, then send the whole object back using a PUT request?

I'm hoping that I just don't quite understand how couchDB works and wants things done.

How do I update one part of a possibly very large object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documents in a document store (like CouchDB is) are conceptually similar to rows in a RDBMS table or files in a filesystem, *not* tables.

In your example, you'd have seperate documents for `myuser1`, one for `myuser2`, and one for `myuser3`, each of which would be small, self-contained and therefore easy and fast to update. Ideally, all of your documents would be like that.

The [CouchDB Guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/) has an excellent chapter on what CouchDB is and why (and when!) it's useful.

Comment: Ah! That's significant .Thank you. So if I have to make bulk updates, I end up sending a separate PUT request for each update? That could make a simple update on 10,000 documents a rather time consuming affair... right?

Comment: Right, it wouldn't be great at that. You could use the [Bulk Document API](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API) to bundle some of the PUT requests together, or do the update on the server side using [update handlers](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers), but there's no `UPDATE` like in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [update handler function](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/ddocs.html%23updatefun) to avoid sending the whole doc to update partial parts.

You will have access to the data you have sent **and** the current version if the doc. Then you alter the doc and give it back to CouchDB.